# How to change content of a div

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been asked before, but if someone could explain in greater detail it would be awesome. I have a div and a table and an image inside this div. I am making a image gallery, so I have two links forward and back, how do I make these links change the image, or rather all the content inside the div. I am very new to javascript, actually I know nothing at all about it, if I could get a step by step instruction that would be awesome, I have tried so of the other post codes but can not get it to work, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sample HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>Dummy page</title></head>
<body>
  <div id="divID">
    <img id="backImg" src="http://test.com/sample.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To change the whole div:

```
var div = document.getElementByID('divID');
div.innerHTML = "<b>This is some html</b>";
```

To just change the image:

```
var img = document.getElementByID('backImg');
img.src = "http://www.host.com/image.jpg';
```

Comment: Ok so I am not sure I understand, or if I am clear in what I am asking, I need to change the whole div because my images are not the same size and styling is different, so each div is different that is why I need to change the whole div.I do not want to use a button to trigger the change rather a link. and that same link needs to be able to keep changing the div to another div up to like 50 different divs... can this be done...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example that I made that might help. Try it out -- http://jsfiddle.net/SuperBoi45/XMSGe/

Here's the code for a quick look:

HTML:

```
<button id="before">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<div id="imageGallery"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var foward = null,
    back = null,
    images = [
        "http://www.toxel.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/conceptcar04.jpg",
        "http://politicolnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/bill-gates-car.jpg",
        "http://www.youthedesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/car-wallpapers19.jpg",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-555c9ae9cfd364db5307b2e8d717a00d",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-01589fb639efec5433a3e30a8a8dd449",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-31f8cbd6627edc1ba9ef2828f3423fdf",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-0f47a0c2db85b5d7c134d41bcdc65b2e",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-739fd589778207e542a6e31873a24433",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-6056a5df58462ea4951a2b328243b7a2",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-59028363fc0f7d0ee7aa1ebc5e72713a",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-eb09864be7a1fbe7e821bc1ee08c3a8b",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-50bd88090e05a452bba67d510ba4a0cc",
        "http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-191b37eea296e90a242d24db90824c5c"
        ];

var img = new Image();
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { // caching the images for performance boost
    img.src = images[i];
}

var image = {
    count: -1,
    next: function() {
        if (image.count == (images.length) - 1) return false;
        image.count += 1;
        $('imageGallery').innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + images[image.count] + "\"\/>";
    },
    previous: function() {
        if (image.count <= 0) return false;
        image.count -= 1;
        $('imageGallery').innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + images[image.count] + "\"\/>";
    }
};

foward = image.next;
back = image.previous;
$('next').addEventListener("click", foward);
$('before').addEventListener("click", back);
```

The best thing about this is that all you have to do is add a new image URL to the array and it will still work.
If you want to change the images but not all the content in the div, I'd recommend putting in another div outside the image gallery.